# How long should it take a professional to lay a patio?

Tags: landscaping, patio

Two people laying paving stones, total area 5m x 3m, paving stones approximately 300x300, 300x600 and 600x600.

Roughly how many man hours is reasonable for this?

In particular, once dug out and hard core already down, how long just to lay the stones?

Edit in light of comments:  This is not about a quote but about work being carried out.  We are being charged by the hour (yes I know now this was stupid) and it took them a day to lay just under half of it.

Comment: As long as there are no issues maybe 2 hours to lay them down max.  However I am assuming that they can get the pile relatively close to patio (200 foot walk and my estimate doubles at least) and that they have no cuts to make.  If they have cuts to make all the way around I could see 5-6 hours, maybe more.

Comment: Also, if this is due to a concern over a quoted price, I would recommend you get a couple more quotes to see how they compare. 70-80% of the quoted hours is likely how long the job would actually take, as every business rightfully needs to build in a small excess for problems and to average over jobs that go horribly wrong. (Edit: 70-80% assumes a "fair" company. Potentially higher percentage for particularly good companies that anticipate and resolve problems quickly, so as not to lose time, and lower to much lower for less reputable companies who expect poor performance from their workers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference point: I recently layed about 3x6 meter sized brick patio in about 4 hours using standard sized bricks. I had a helper who I hired off craigslist to mov the bricks from the street to the backyard(where the patio is) I payed him $60 for four hours of work and I feel like that was pretty generous. I consider landscaping to be unqualified labor so anything more than minimum wage for bigger projects is too much

Comment: Isn't it quite difficult laying a patio properly without slabs going wonky or it sinking or cracking or anything?  I would have been way too nervous to try it myself.

Comment: You have to get the base gravel compacted right and the sand properly smoothed. You also need to get the drainage tilt right. You almost always end up having to cut a row of bricks or two to make things fit. My 10X15 foot patio has held up quite nicely for 12 years, and I started out a complete amateur. -BTW instead of renting one of those vibratory tools for compaction, you can mount a half horse 1720 rpm motor on a cafetria tray, with a 5 Lb iron weight attached loosely to the motor shaft. Jiggle like crazy, but it does the job and spares you the $75 an hour fee for a rental unit.

Answer (score 2):

I am a professional landscaper and I know that yes the majority of the work a brain dead monkey could do but when it comes to the skilled work it is a lot harder than you think!!! I can lay about 25 square metres of random lay rough cut slabs a day. Anything over 20 is a good speed. /Obviously it all depends on how accurate your base is and the quality of slabs.

On another note £80 a day (9 hour day) is about the going rate for a basic labourer!!

Answer (score 1):

I like to average about 30m2 per day on random slabs I reckon my 10 year old could lay more than they have 15m2 for two men is a max 1 days work even with cuts adjusting manhole covers etc

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. There's good info here, but it's hard to understand without sentences. Would you mind cleaning it up a bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pointed up it would take me a day if I have to make the mixes too but I expect £200+/day so two men at £120 should be able to get it done in a day. They sound like amateurs with the wrong tools to me. Very common for groundworkers to say they can lay when they can't!